# Using gawk to extract rows with string in a column

Tags: regex, awk

I was trying to extract rows from a tab separated file, if it contained a certain word in the 4th column. For example, if input file test.txt is:

```
chr     8       1234    abc ; xyz
chr     8       1255    abc
chr     8       987     xyz
chr     8       5467    jxyzm
```

The following code correctly outputs only the 1st and 3rd line:

```
gawk -F"\t" ' { if($4 ~ /\<xyz\>/) print $0 } ' test.txt >> test.out
```

However, when I try to run this in a loop, in a bash script, my output file is blank. the code I am using is:

```
while read id
do    
    OFILE=${ODIR}/${id}.txt
    gawk -v id="$id" -F"\t" ' { if($4 ~ /\<id\>/) print $0 } ' ${IFILE} >> ${OFILE}
done < ${GFILE}
```

The file ${GFILE} has one word per line, e.g.:

```
xyz
fg45
tre2y
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Edited to:

1. Add fourth row in input file
2. Added -v id="$id" to command...script still doesn't work!

Comment: Why are you using `bash` loop for this when `awk` can do in one line?

Comment: The pattern to search for is different, and read from input file ${GFILE}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can very well use `awk` to read search patterns from one file and find matches in other like this:

```
awk -F '\t' '
NR == FNR {
   words[$1]
   next
}
{
   for (w in words)
      if (index($4, w)) {
         print > w ".txt"
         break
      }
}' "$GFILE" "$IFILE"
```

Then check output:

```
cat xyz.txt
```

```
chr     8       1234    abc ; xyz
chr     8       987     xyz
```

---

If you really-really want to fix your shell script then here it is:

```
while read id; do
    awk -F '\t' -v id="$id" '$4 ~ id' "$IFILE" > "$id.txt"
done < "$GFILE"
```

Comment: It also needs to output the 1st row (i.e. with 'abc ; xyz'). Also, the output for each pattern is to be written to a separate file ${id}.txt

Comment: Yes, this will produce the desired output. However, I am still wondering why my one liner didn't work. One mistake was not specifying the shell variable correctly (with '-v id="$id"'), but even with that it still needs tweaking. Since this operation is a small part of the shell script that execute, I am still on the lookout for a shell scripting solution! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: ok I have provided you a fix of your shell script also but recommended approach is using single `awk`

Comment: @brian to be 100% clear - do not do this with a shell loop, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). If you think you need to do it with a shell loop for some reason then post a new question so we can help you do whatever you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: Ed, thanks for that link! I was not aware of the issues involved. This is something that I need to educate myself on.